# Upgrade curl on solaris

Tags: curl

I currently have curl 7.28.0. I have to upgrade to latest. I dont have yum instead have pkgadd. how do I do? I tried to do pkgadd by downloading latest pkg but it installs under /opt/csw/bin. I need under /usr/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which version of Solaris, but assuming that you are on a not too old version of Solaris (e.g. > 10), then you would simply do:

```
$ pkg install curl
```

At the moment this will give you curl v7.45 which is at least [fairly recent](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/releases.html). It will install in `/usr/bin` as you request. If you want the cutting edge then I don't think you have any other option than to build yourself.

(Since 2011, when Solaris 11 was introduced, installing and managing packages got so much easier. Previously the command was `pkgadd` and it was sometimes difficult to find the package you wanted and they would install in various places, dependent on who made the package. Now you just do `pkg` and the [repository](http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/catalog.shtml) of open source software that Oracle provides for Solaris hasn't so far let me down.)